# Chrome extenshion. Получение данных с входящего запроса на сайте

Tags: javascript, api, post, chrome-extension, fetch

При загрузке страницы, на сайт приходит очень много входящих данных с различных АПИ. Меня интересует определенный реквест, в ответе которого находятся нужные мне данные. Вручную я все прекрасно вижу и понимаю, что мне нужно. Но как мне отфильтровать входящие запросы и взять данные только с нужного?

Я пробовал много вариантов, и вот последний, который хоть что-то сделал:

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        console.log(details, details.url) //тут приходят ссылки, но не все
        if (details.url.includes("your-api-url")) { // сюда пока не дошёл
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, { type: "API_RESPONSE", data: details });
        }
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }
);
```

Итого выходит, что я получаю список входящих ссылок, но там только `type: image` .

Как можно получить эти данные в json?

Comment: Каким образом вы собираетесь фильтровать запросы? Как я понял вы хотите их фильтровать по ссылке. При этом какую ссылку вы хотите, вы не сказали.

Comment: @ΝNL993 допустим, ссылка выглядит так: https://api.domain.com/v3/items . Напрямую получить доступ нельзя, т.к. там около 20 параметров, из которых есть уникальный ID сессии, который, как я понял, генерируется, когда первинчый запрос на открытие страницы отправлен. Т.к. это расширение, то я могу вызывать свой код еще до начала получения данных, т.к. данные грузятся тоже там не сразу.